# Rustの型エラーで二次元配列が書き換えられない

Tags: rust

最近Rustを学び始めて，現在以下のようなコードを書いています．

```
static TABLE:[[u8; 4]; 4] =[
    [ 3,  6,  7, 14],
    [ 1, 11, 13,  5],
    [ 8,  2,  4,  9],
    [10, 15,  0, 12]
];

fn main() {
    let mut input: [[u8; 2]; 4] = [[4, 8], [3, 10], [9, 1], [0, 3]];
    let output = func(input, TABLE);
    for row in output.iter() {
        for data in row.iter() {
            println!("{}", data);
        }
    }
}

fn func(input:[[u8; 2]; 4], table:[[u8; 4]; 4]) -> [[u8; 2]; 4] {
    let mut t = input.clone();
    for i in t.iter() {
        for j in i.iter() {
            let y = j % 4;
            let x = (j - y) / 4;
            j = table[x as usize][y as usize].clone();
        }
    }

    t;
}
```

funcは，二次元配列inputの要素の値(Z)から二次元配列tableの座標(X, Y)を算出して，Zをその値に書き換えた配列を新たに返すという関数です．

これをコンパイルしようとすると以下のエラーでコンパイルに失敗します．

> src/main.rs:24:17: 24:54 error: mismatched types:
>    expected `&u8`, found `u8`
>   (expected &-ptr, found u8) [E0308]
>   src/main.rs:24　j = **table[x as usize][y as usize].clone();**

j は t[〜][〜] の値の参照で，それを書き換えることによって t にそれが反映されることを期待していたのですが，そのやり方が間違っているようで悩んでいます．

ちなみに以下のような出力を期待しています．

```
1
8
14
4
2
6
3
14
```

どのようにすればこのような出力を得られるでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.iter()はimmutableなreferenceを返すので書き換えれません．.iter_mut()を使って以下のようにすると所望の出力が得られました．

```
fn func(input:[[u8; 2]; 4], table:[[u8; 4]; 4]) -> [[u8; 2]; 4] {
    let mut t = input.clone();
    for i in t.iter_mut() {
        for j in i.iter_mut() {
            let y = *j % 4;
            let x = (*j - y) / 4;
            *j = table[x as usize][y as usize].clone();
        }
    }
    return t;
}
```

Comment: immutableなreference、ですか？

Comment: まちがった回答を修正しました.